# Getting Origami-pdf to work with Amazon S3 files

Tags: pdf, amazon-s3, digital-signature

I've implemented a local script to insert digital signatures into local pdf files recurring to Origami, but don't quite know what would be the best approach to do this within a rails server, and with amazon s3 stored files.

I am guessing i would need to download the file from s3 to my server (or capture it before uploading to amazon, which is what i am doing with paperclip) insert the signature, and sent it back to s3 again.

Here is the PDF.read method in pdf.rb file of origami solution:

```
 class << self

      #
      # Reads and parses a PDF file from disk.
      #
      def read(filename, options = {})
        filename = File.expand_path(filename) if filename.is_a?(::String)
        PDF::LinearParser.new(options).parse(filename)
      end
```

How could i adapt this so that i treat an in-memory binary file?

Do you have any suggestions?

You can find more about origami [here](http://code.google.com/p/origami-pdf/wiki/GettingStarted)

And my code below

```
require 'openssl'

begin
  require 'origami'
rescue LoadError
  ORIGAMIDIR = "C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\origami-1.2.4\lib"
  $: << ORIGAMIDIR
  require 'origami'
end
include Origami

INPUTFILE = "Sample.pdf"
@inputfile = String.new(INPUTFILE)
OUTPUTFILE = @inputfile.insert(INPUTFILE.rindex("."),"_signed")
CERTFILE = "certificate.pem"
RSAKEYFILE = "private_key.pem"
passphrase = "your passphrase"

key4pem=File.read RSAKEYFILE

key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new key4pem, passphrase
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read CERTFILE)

pdf = PDF.read(INPUTFILE)
page = pdf.get_page(1)

# Add signature annotation (so it becomes visibles in pdf document)

sigannot = Annotation::Widget::Signature.new
sigannot.Rect = Rectangle[:llx => 89.0, :lly => 386.0, :urx => 190.0, :ury => 353.0]

page.add_annot(sigannot)

# Sign the PDF with the specified keys
pdf.sign(cert, key, 
  :method => 'adbe.pkcs7.sha1',
  :annotation => sigannot, 
  :location => "Portugal", 
  :contact => "myemail@email.tt", 
  :reason => "Proof of Concept"
)

# Save the resulting file
pdf.save(OUTPUTFILE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PDF.read` and `PDF.save` methods both accept either a file path or a Ruby IO object.

One method to create a PDF instance from a string (which, I suppose, is what you mean when you say "in-memory") is to use a [StringIO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) object.

For example, the following session in the Origami shell will create a PDF instance, save it to a StringIO object and reload it using its own output string.

```
>>> PDF.new.save(strio = StringIO.new)
...

>>> strio.string
"%PDF-1.0\r\n1 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n\t/Pages 2 0 R ..."

>>> strio.reopen(strio.string, 'r')
#<StringIO:0xffbea6cc>

>>> pdf = PDF.read(strio)
...

>>> pdf.class
Origami::PDF
```

Comment: Actually I wasn't referring to a string, but to a File instance, like the one exposed by paperclip  to its processors (https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

Comment: PDF.save() seems to be expecting a file path...I tried to enter my paperclip file object, and got an error noticing that the input wasn't a string

Comment: It seems its not a File instance afterall : `can't convert Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter into String`

Comment: You can either implement a `write` method for `Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter`, or get the filename or File instance associated with that object.

Comment: I don't think its a problem. I can use file.path for the save. The fact is that read receives "file" as an argument, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After a deep further analysis into the origami [code](http://code.google.com/p/origami-pdf/source/search?q=parser.rb&origq=parser.rb&btnG=Search%20Trunk), i noticed that PDF.Read accepts a binary file, and so instead of sending the local file path, we can send the file instance as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

As @MrWater wrote, `Origami::PDF.read` accepts a stream (more precisely, the `Origami::PDF::LinearParser` does, look at the source [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/origami/Origami/PDF/LinearParser)).

Here's my simple solution:

```rb
require 'open-uri'

# pdf_url = 'http://someurl.com/somepdf.pdf'
pdf = Origami::PDF.read(URI.parse(pdf_url))
```

### References

- [open-uri URI](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/open-uri/URI)
- [Origami::PDF::LinearParser](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/origami/Origami/PDF/LinearParser)